# how to fill the object value inside nested array of object?

Tags: javascript, angular

Actually I want to push the object on each loop inside 'next'

The below i want to push simlar next object
code:

```
arrayOfObject = [{
  "id":"100",
   "next": [{
        id":"101",
        "next": [{
            id":"102",
           "next": [] // how will reach dyanmically and i don't how many iteration need to to reach this empty 'next'
        }]
   }]
  }
 ]
```

can you please help any one to achieve this.

Comment: so you need to find first empty `next`?

Comment: why do you need to do it? can't you just do something at the area where you use your object later like `next.length ? next : [fallback]`

Comment: @Endless - i have requirement  in my project. to execute in order need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution might be to use a `while` loop to traverse down to the bottom of the nested array... once you have a reference, you can push any object you need.

```js
const arrayOfObject = [{
  "id":"100",
   "next": [{
        "id":"101",
        "next": [{
            "id":"102",
           "next": [] 
        }]
   }]
  }
 ]
 
 let childArray = arrayOfObject
 while (childArray[0] && childArray[0].next) childArray = childArray[0].next;
 
 childArray.push({"test":"testing"})
 
 console.log(childArray)
 console.log(arrayOfObject)
```

Comment: Thank you, Marshal. it very simple. could you please share any other solution with ES6+